# Discord.py, getting duplicate messages in cogs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I recently moved all my discord.py bot code into different cogs. But some of them fail to work and most of them send duplicate messages/embeds every time they are used.

I am not sure how to fix this so ima ask someone smarter than me.

Ex: Giveaway command:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import random
import time


class GiveawayCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self._last_member = None

    @commands.command()
    async def giveaway(self, ctx, timee, group: discord.Role, *, prize):
        seconds = 0
        counter = 0
        user = discord.Member
        role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == group, ctx.guild.roles)
        for i in timee:
            if i.lower().endswith("d"):
                seconds += int(timee[:-1]) * 60 * 60 * 24
                counter = f"{seconds // 60 // 60 // 24} days"
            if i.lower().endswith("h"):
                seconds += int(timee[:-1]) * 60 * 60
                counter = f"{seconds // 60 // 60} hours"
            elif i.lower().endswith("m"):
                seconds += int(timee[:-1]) * 60
                counter = f"{seconds // 60} minutes"
            elif i.lower().endswith("s"):
                seconds += int(timee[:-1])
                counter = f"{seconds} seconds"
        winner = None
        giveawayembed = discord.Embed(
            title=" New Giveaway! ",
            colour=discord.Color.green()
        )

        giveawayembed.add_field(name="Prize:", value="{}".format(prize), inline=False)
        giveawayembed.add_field(name="Hosted by:", value=f"{ctx.author.mention}", inline=False)
        giveawayembed.add_field(name="Ends in:", value=f"{counter}")
        giveawayembed.add_field(name="Role required:", value=f"{group}")

        msg = await ctx.send(embed=giveawayembed)
        await msg.add_reaction("")

        await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
        message = await ctx.fetch_message(msg.id)
        users = await message.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        users.pop(users.index(ctx.guild.me))
        users.pop(users.index(ctx.author))

        winner = random.choice(users)
        if winner.has_roles(role) is False:
            winner = random.choice(users)

        else:
            winner = random.choice(users)
            await ctx.send(f"**Congrats {winner.mention}!**\nPlease contact {ctx.author.mention} about your prize.")


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(GiveawayCog(client))
```

Error:

[Double embed pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbu1O.png)

Error 2:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence

(This error happens even though I react to the message)

Thx for any help, it is appreciated! :D
Also here is the documentation for Discord.py: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: are you sure that you only have one instance of the bot running/the commands only in one place?

Comment: I really think you are probably running the commands in two different places at the same time, I just copied and tested your code and it didn't repeat itself

Comment: Make sure that you dont have `bot.process_comands(message)`  twice somewhere.

You dont need to have it in cogs listeners.

Also, `role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == group, ctx.guild.roles)` will not work in this code. `group` will be already a `discord.Role` at that point, so this `find` will always return `None`

Comment: I literally rebooted my computer because I thought I had 2 instances running..., hmmm.

Comment: Also, I did some more testing and when I don't react to the embed I get this error:
`line 49, in giveaway
    users.pop(users.index(ctx.author))
ValueError: <Member id={my member id} name='Dromera555' discriminator='{my discriminator}' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id={the test server} name='TEST SERVER' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=2>> is not in list`

...

Comment: I don't know how or why but when I came back to my computer rn only one message was sent so I guess it was that 2 instances were running... Welp I guess error 1 got answered. Do any of you guys have any ideas for error 2?